# How can I get rid of RequestOptionsArgs in the below code

Tags: javascript, angular, migration

I am migrating my project from angular 7 to 8. I replaced Http with HttpClient but am stuck in the below code. How should I get rid of RequestOptionsArgs.

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http/src/interfaces';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LocalDataSource } from '../local/local.data-source';
import { ServerSourceConf } from './server-source.conf';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
export declare class ServerDataSource extends LocalDataSource {
    protected http: HttpClient;
    protected conf: ServerSourceConf;
    protected lastRequestCount: number;
    constructor(http: HttpClient, conf?: ServerSourceConf | {});
    count(): number;
    getElements(): Promise<any>;
    /**
     * Extracts array of data from server response
     * @param res
     * @returns {any}
     */
    protected extractDataFromResponse(res: any): Array<any>;
    /**
     * Extracts total rows count from the server response
     * Looks for the count in the heders first, then in the response body
     * @param res
     * @returns {any}
     */
    protected extractTotalFromResponse(res: any): number;
    protected requestElements(): Observable<any>;
    protected createRequestOptions(): RequestOptionsArgs;
    protected addSortRequestOptions(requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs;
    protected addFilterRequestOptions(requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs;
    protected addPagerRequestOptions(requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs;
}
```

This file location is ../node_modules/ng2-smart-table/lib/data-source/server/server.data-source.d.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own interfaces and change the imports to your own interface, but there will be some changes. your interface will look like :-

```
export interface RequestOptionsArgs { 
  url?: string|null;
  method?: string;
  search?: string|{[key: string]: any | any[]}|null;
  params?: string|{[key: string]: any | any[]}|null;
  headers?: HttpHeaders|null;
  body?: any;
  withCredentials?: boolean|null;
  responseType?: 'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'text'|'json';
}
```

then you can change your implementation as per these parameters and map these to httpclient.

Comment: I've never edited a file from node module so I don't know what this code means. So I just copy pasted your code and it works for now. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: this interface is not available in http client, you create your own file in source code not in node_modules. so i gave your an interface similar to requestoptions arg. can you please mark it as solution if it worked?